# Backbone - Merge 2 Collections together?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Suppose there are 2 Collections, representing respectively `/api/page/1` and `/api/page/2`; is there anyway (through Underscore, for example) to merge these 2 Collections into a new, single Collection?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you haven't fetched the collection yet, you can fetch the first one, then fetch the second one with the {add : true} flag and the second one will be merged into the first one:

```
collection.fetch({data : {page : 2});
=> [{id: 1, article : "..."}, {id: 2, article : "..."}];
collection.fetch({data : {page : 2}, add : true });
=> [{id: 1, article : "..."}, {id: 2, article : "..."}, {id: 3, article : "..."}];
```

**Option 2**

If you've already fetched the collections and have them stored in two variables, you can just add all contents of the second collection into the first one:

```
collection1.add(collection2.toJSON());
```

This options suffers from the fact that the first collection will fire the "add" event when the second collection is added to it.  If this has side effects such as undesired UI that re-renders due to this event, you can suppress it by adding the {silent : true} flag

```
collection1.add(collection2.toJSON(), {silent : true});
```

**Option 3**

If you just need the JSON format of these collections, i.e. for HTML template rendering purposes, you can just reduce everything to JS literals (arrays, objects):

```
collection1.toJSON().concat(collection2.toJSON());
=> [{id: 1, article : "..."}, {id: 2, article : "..."}, ...];
```

**Option 4 = Option 2 + 3**

If you've already fetched both collections, you can reduce to JS literals and add everything to a fresh Backbone collection

```
var rawCollection = collection1.toJSON().concat(collection2.toJSON());
var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection(rawCollection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation =)

Comment: -1. If you call toJSON() you lose the reference to the models. If you create a model, insert it into a collection, merge the collection with another one, change the model, the model in the last collection isn't updated. This will become a nightmare to debug. It would be ok if you wanted to copy the models and keep them separated, but it isn't the norm and should be pointed out.

Comment: If you already have the two collections, you should probably be using any of the the answers below that use: `collection1.add(collection2.models);`

Comment: Although could work, the answer as a whole is quite misleading. Real answer: _collection1.add(collection2.models);_ as described in: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

Comment: If you use Collection.add, you likely want the {merge:true} option. (see http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add). Also, fetch by default merges (but in my older version 0.9.10, it by default resets and needs option "update:true" to merge - look at your backbone.js Collection "fetch" method).

Comment: You can pass JSON into set/add (in addition to models). JSON will be automatically "vivified as instances of the model" if "model" property is defined - http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add. "add" simply calls "set" with options defaulted to add: true, remove: false, merge: false (see http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js, search for "add:"; however in my older backbone "set" is undefined and the code is in "update" and "add").

Comment: on version 1.1.2 it requires {remove: false} option

Answer (score 41):

try this,
collection is array of models

```
collection1.add(collection2.models);
```

if we use

```
 collection1.add(collection2.toJSON());
```

then reference chage

Comment: +1 That is the only real answer, should really be the accepted one. See documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add. You can also decide whether to accept duplicates or not by passing: {merge: true}

Answer (score 5):

```
collection.add(models, [options])
```

Collection is array of models

```
collection.models
```

returns array of models

Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection.

```
A = Backbone.Collection;
collection1 = new A([
    {key, 'value'},                  //model1
    {key : value1}                   //model2 in collection1
]);

B = Backbone.Collection;
collection2 = new B([
    {key1, 'value'},                 //model1
    {key1 : value1}                  //model2 in collection2
]);


collection1.add(collection2.models);  //now, collection1 has four models..
```

Answer (score 5):

use

```
collection.models
```

insted of

```
collection.toJSON()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that by doing this, you lose the semantic tied to `/api/page/{1, 2}/`.

It also seems to me that neither backbone, neither underscore, provides you with a function/method doing exactly what you're trying to do.

So your options :

- create a new collection, add each item from your previous collections;
- add first collection items to the second one

But you probably already knew this.

Comment: Yes. I think the solution here is to have 1 collection and you `fetch({data:{page:1}, add:true})`. Increment the page value with each `fetch()` and add the newest batch/page of models into the collection.

Comment: Your solution seems quite pretty, however I think he already has the collections fetched, and probably wants to avoid refetching the data. But if it is note the case, then your way is A Good Way.

Answer (score 0):

Collection.models provides direct access to the array of moels and Collection.add will take an array of models as an argument.