# Merging two collections together in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, merge, backbone.js-collections

I am having a problem merging two **Backbone.js** **Collections** into each other...

I've done lots of searching, and came up with an article very similar to this issue: [Backbone - Merge 2 Collections together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384088/backbone-merge-2-collections-together)

This existing answer provided plenty of ways to do it, however none of them work for me.

The following is a snippet of code from by **Backbone.js** class that has the issue. I tried commenting in it the best I could to explain my problem further.

```
var THAT=this;

//create dynamic channel collection
this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection = new DynamicChannelsCollection();
this.data.dynamicChannelsModel = new DynamicChannelsModel();

this.data.sortModel = new TVPModel({
  sortField:'date_created',
  sortDirection:'DESC',
  pageItems:10,
  page:0,
  searchString:'',
  searchFields:['text']
});

this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.sortedFetch(this.data.sortModel);

// merge the dynamic channel collection into the standard channel collection
console.log('dynamicChannelsCollection: ', this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection);
console.log('collectionListCollection: ', THAT.data.collectionListCollection);

// HOW DO I MERGE THE 2 COLLECTIONS ABOVE PROPERLY?
// What I've Tried:

// 0) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.toJSON().concat(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON());
// 1) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON());
// 2) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON(), {silent:true});
// 3) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON());
// 4) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.models);
// 5) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON(), { silent:true });
// 6) THAT.data.collectionListCollection.add(this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.models, { silent:true });
// 7) 
    //var mergeCollection = this.data.dynamicChannelsCollection.toJSON().concat(THAT.data.collectionListCollection.toJSON());
    //THAT.data.collectionListCollection = new Backbone.Collection(mergeCollection);

// I need THAT.data.collectionListCollection to be a merged array of the two arrays above
console.log('collections merged: ', THAT.data.collectionListCollection);
```

There are two `console.logs` to output the two **Collections** to verify they exist. 
Then there is a third log that outputs the merged **Collection**. 
The following two screenshots are the results I received every time...
The merged collection always contained either 0 or 4 elements (when it should contain 7).

How can I properly merge these two collections?

**Here is the contents of DynamicChannelCollection from console.log:**

```
child {app: Object, length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, url: "/api/entity?n=10&o=date_created&od=DESC&entityType=5"}
_byId
:
Object
app
:
Object
length
:
3
models
:
Array[3]
0
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c77"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431935"
__proto__
:
constructor
1
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c78"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431934"
__proto__
:
constructor
2
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c79"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431933"
__proto__
:
constructor
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
url
:
"/api/entity?n=10&o=date_created&od=DESC&entityType=5"
__proto__
:
constructor
```

**Here is the contents of CollectionListCollection from console.log:**

```
child {app: Object, length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object}
_byId
:
Object
_events
:
Object
app
:
Object
hasFetched
:
true
length
:
4
models
:
Array[4]
0
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c80"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431932"
__proto__
:
constructor
1
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c81"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431931"
__proto__
:
constructor
2
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c82"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66431930"
__proto__
:
constructor
3
:
child
_changing
:
false
_events
:
Object
_pending
:
false
_previousAttributes
:
Object
app
:
Object
attributes
:
Object
changed
:
Object
cid
:
"c83"
collection
:
child
id
:
"66252499"
__proto__
:
constructor
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array[0]
url
:
"/api/player?n=10&o=date_created&od=DESC"
__proto__
:
constructor
```

I added the text of the `Collections` before merge as requested. The `Models` in each `Collection` are definitely different from each other.

Comment: Here is a good answer: [Backbone - Merge 2 Collections together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384088/backbone-merge-2-collections-together)

Comment: I've already reviewed that existing answer, and mentioned in the post that I have already seen this and have tried all the options on there.

Comment: I'm closing this question as duplicate because it is not yet in a good shape to be answered. Once you edit it, maybe it can be reopened. Please replace the screenshot with actual text. Use `console.log` if you must to output good diagnostic information and use that for your question. Moreover, you're not explaining whether your collection classes are stock `Backbone.Collection` classes that you've just renamed or whether they are customized. If the latter, maybe your customization is causing problem? But we can't know. In addition, you are not showing what the collections contain before merge.

Comment: (continued) Did you know that collections behave roughly like sets? If you have the set `1, 2, 3` and add `1, 2, 3, 4` to it, the result is `1, 2, 3, 4`, not `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4`. Maybe the collections you are trying to merge contain models for the same data?? (And then having lengths 3 and 4 at the start and 4 at the end would not be wrong.) We cannot know because the question does not say. (The 0-length results you also report can be explained by the fact that some of what you tried is utterly wrong.)

Comment: I added the actual text from the screenshots as requested and removed screenshots.

Comment: You've edited your question but you've not heeded this bit of advice: " Use `console.log` if you must to *output good diagnostic information and use that for your question*." (Emphasis added.) Just dumping a collection with `console.log` does not tell you much about what it contains. It shows the number of elements. The rest has either nothing to do with what the collection contains, or very little. You should be iterating through each collection's elements and dump the model's `url` and `id`.